# Getting audio samples from a .wav file in Xamarin.Forms android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, wav, naudio

I'm trying to get the raw audio samples from a .wav file. I've been using NAudio for Windows and GTK, but it looks like it's impossible to use it in the android project. Is there an alternative library or NuGet package for getting the raw audio samples on Android? If not, how should I go about extracting the raw samples from the wav file?

Comment: recommendations for tools are off-topic

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I didn't expand on my question enough. If there isn't a way to do so easily with a certain library, then I'd like to know how to do it myself.

Comment: Have you read the docs on androids audio apis?

Comment: A little. I could only find stuff for recording and playing audio, but I'll need the raw samples to manipulate them.

Comment: Maybe open an issue at [github - NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). Now that .net 6 is released, perhaps someone there would be willing to add support for Android.